# Order of a dilation and a reflection of a function

Tags: functions, reflection

$Parent function$: $f(x)$ = $\sqrt{x}$

$A$: the function is reflected in the y-axis and then translated 2 units to the right.

$B$: the function is translated 2 units to the right, then reflected in the y-axis.

for $A$, my working outs:

```
    f(-x) - reflected in the y-axis
```

Now, I have a doubt.  After reflected in the y-axis, will the transformation be included in the reflection?

i.e should it be: $f(-(x-2))$ or $f(-x+(-2))$

My understanding suggests that it should be $f(-x-2)$.

---

Similarly for $B$,

```
    f(x-2) - two units to the right
```

Now, should it be

$f(-(x-2))$ or $f(-x-2)$

I think it should be $f(-x+2)$

---

I know, if it was reflected in the x-axis, and translated two units upwards, then it would have been:

$-f(x) + 2$

And, Reversing the operation: $-[f(x) + 2]$ = $-f(x) - 2$

That is why I have doubts regarding the order of reflection in the y-axis.

I would appreciate if you could provide an answer to my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction for A clearly says "reflect, **then** translate". So you reflect first:
$$f_1(x) = f(-x)$$
Then you translate the result:
$$f_2(x) = f_1(x -2)$$
Similarly for B. Do the operations in the order that the problem says to do them.

Comment: No, that is not what you get when you do the operations I indicated. if $f_1(x) = f(-x)$, what is $f_1(x-2)$?

Comment: so $f(-x+2) right?

Comment: But why? I thought it should be f(-x) -> f(-x + -2), because the reflection on the y-axis is implemented and then we translate two units to the right. When we reflect in x-axis, let's say, the function is reflected in x-axis and translated 2 units upwards, then it will be -f(x) + 2, right?

Comment: Never mind, I have cleared my misconceptions. Thank you very much.

Comment: It was all a matter of misapplying function notation, but in both cases, while I was writing my reply, you worked it out yourself before I could finish. Which is best, I think. Good luck.

Comment: Yes definitely. Thanks once again.